# Storage sizing for index rebuild

Tags: nexus

I'm trying to rebuild an index for a proxy maven repository (https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/staging/) which has a downloaded index size of 5.4GiB.

Although the nexus-tmp-folder's partition has about 30GiB free space the reindexing fails because of

```
2016-07-21 12:58:30,718+0200 WARN [pxpool-1-thread-13] org.sonatype.nexus.index.tasks.RepairIndexTask - Scheduled task (RepairIndexTask) failed :: Repairing repository index "Java/Sonatype OSSRH Staging" from path / and below. (started 2016-07-21T11:51:54+02:00, runtime 1:06:36.533)
java.io.IOException: No space left on device
...
```

I am using nexus oss 2.11.1-01.

Can anyone tell me how much storage space to provide for indexing operations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nexus needs to uncompress that index in the temporary directory, and process it.  I'm not sure exactly what the uncompressed size of that index plus processing space needed is, but seems it's more than 30Gb. :-)

I'd suggest moving the temporary directory location to a partition that has more space.  You can find instructions for doing that here:

https://support.sonatype.com/hc/en-us/articles/213464938-How-to-configure-the-Nexus-temporary-directory